# starting application on websphere 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am deploying my application on websphere 8.5.5.
When I start the application from the console I got an error with the following stacktrace in systemErr.out file.
Do you know what is the cause of this exception ?

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: null
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
```

Comment: Check for any nested exceptions or check in the SystemOut.log for any other messages during application startup.

Comment: What is the status of your issue? Can you edit question to show more of the stack trace?

Comment: The issue was related to the jsf.

Comment: I also face the same issue using websphere and jsf as well. Can you tell me what is the root cause and solution for this ?? Looking for your earlier response.

Comment: I too face the same issue. Have you found the root cause?

Comment: Start Application or cluster primary and check and start server from WebSphere Applicaion Server Type and turn tail -f SystemOut.log in run start server from console and see many LOG of Application. As LOG of SystemErr.LOG of enviroment not Application. This you need is LOG of Application when start server please.